# Understanding a proof about $\lambda$-supercompact cardinal

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, model-theory

I have trouble understanding the proof of this
[Lemma 20.15 from Jech's Set Theory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDydp.png), could someone explain why is $(2^\alpha)^M = (\alpha^+)^M = \alpha^+$?

Comment: There are two equalities there: $(2^\alpha)^M=(\alpha^+)^M$ and $(\alpha^+)^M=\alpha^+$. Which one(s) don't you see how to prove?

Comment: with regard to the latter equality, all that’s actually needed for the argument is $(\alpha^+)^M\le \alpha^+$, which is always true for inner models.

Comment: @NoahSchweber especially the first one, I think the second one is clearer now.

Comment: That’s elementarity: Since GCH holds below $\kappa$ in $V$, GCH holds below $j(\kappa)$ in M.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you! I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly already answered in the comments, but to get this off the board...

We have $(2^\alpha)^M = (\alpha^+)^M$ by elementarity: since $\forall \beta<\kappa\; 2^\beta =\beta^+$ holds in $V,$ $\forall \beta < j(\kappa)\; 2^\beta = \beta^+$ holds in $M,$ so since $\alpha < j(\kappa),$ $(2^\alpha)^M= (\alpha^+)^M.$

As for why $(\alpha^+)^M=\alpha^+,$ by $\lambda$-supercompactness, $M$ is closed under $\alpha$-sequences, so any bijection between $\alpha$ and $(\alpha^+)^M$ would need to be in $M,$ but that's impossible by definition of $(\alpha^+)^M.$